# Class Diagram from mxml - flex file

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, diagrams

So i am building an application on flex for a client and he asked me if i can provide him with a class diagram. I was wondering if there is a simple way to do it with a program (like visio or something) as done in java. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grant Skinner's](http://gskinner.com/) [gModeler](http://www.gskinner.com/gmodeler/) might be of interest.

Cited from the gModeler site:

> gModeler is a free online UML diagramming and documentation tool,
>   targetted at developers working with ECMA 262 languages such as
>   FlashMX's Actionscript, and Javascript. In addition to it's
>   diagramming capabilities, it exports HTML documentation, FlashMX XML
>   documentation (for the Action Panel and Reference Panel) and stub code
>   (class code).

Comment: that did the trick. i get a few autogenerated classes but still you just helped me save like 3 hours of work. thanx